# Where do I find all of the Daedric quests and artifacts in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The only quest I completed was "Mind Of Madness" with Sheogorath, which was hilarious, and I would like to know where to find the rest of the Daedric quests.

Comment: See: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Quests

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the Daedric artefacts are rewards for Deadric quests, here's a list of all of the quests:

- "Azura: [The Black Star](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Star_%28Quest%29)"

  - Start location: Azura's Shrine
- "Boethiah: [Boethiah's Calling](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Boethiah%27s_Calling)"

  - Start location: Read "Boethiah's Proving" (Known locations: Abandoned House in Markarth, on or under a bookshelf. The College of Winterhold, can be bought from Urag gro-Shub. )
- "Clavicus Vile: [A Daedra's Best Friend](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend)"

  - Start location: Falkreath
- "Hermaeus Mora: [Discerning the Transmundane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane)"

  - Start location: Septimus Signus' Outpost
- "Hircine: [Ill Met By Moonlight](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ill_Met_By_Moonlight)"

  - Start location: The jail in Falkreath's Guard Barracks
- "Malacath: [The Cursed Tribe](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cursed_Tribe)"

  - Start location: Largashbur
- "Mehrunes Dagon: [Pieces of the Past](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Pieces_of_the_Past)"

  - Start location: Talk to Silus Vesuius (Dawnstar)
- "Mephala: [The Whispering Door](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Whispering_Door)"

  - Start location: Talk to Hulda the bartender at The Bannered Mare in Whiterun
- "Meridia: [The Break of Dawn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Break_of_Dawn)"

  - Start location: Statue to Meridia
- "Molag Bal: [The House of Horrors](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_House_of_Horrors)"

  - Start location: Markarth
- "Namira: [The Taste of Death](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Taste_of_Death)"

  - Start location: Discus rumours with Kleppr at the Silver-Blood Inn
- "Peryite: [The Only Cure](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Only_Cure)"

  - Start location: Approach Kesh at the Shrine to Peryite.
- "Sanguine: [A Night to Remember](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_Night_to_Remember)"

  - Start location: Accept the drinking contest at any tavern.
- "Sheogorath: [The Mind of Madness](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Mind_of_Madness)"

  - Start location: Solitude
- "Vaermina: [Waking Nightmare](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Nightmare)"

  - Start location: Speaking to Erandur, in the Windpeak Inn in Dawnstar.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daedric_Quests_%28Skyrim%29

Answer (score 0):

Rare weapons, armour, and other items can be discovered from these quests for a list of rare enchantment weapons commonly mistaken for Daedric artifacts. Please refer to the "unique enchantments" page of the Elder Scrolls Wiki.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Couple things: if you're referring to an off-site resource, it's better to include a link; even when you include the link, you need to summarize the relevant information (like an example weapon); I'm also not sure what motivated you to post this information. It doesn't seem that relevant to the question.