# Where do I get Daedric weapons at level 40?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I really want to get a Daedric weapon, but I am only level 40. Could someone please help me get one without smithing or using the Atronach Forge?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to attain Daedric weaponry, one is through the Daedric quests:

- [A list of all the Daedric quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152579/where-do-i-find-all-of-the-daedric-quests-and-artifacts-in-skyrim)
- [A description of the Daedric quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/how-many-daedric-missions-are-there-that-give-you-armor-as-a-reward)

Another way is through smithing. You will need to be at least level 90 in the Smithing skill to make it yourself, but if you are level 45-50 (overall) you will start finding them as loot (very rare) and as you level up, it will become more common.

And last but not least, there are a few missions that involve summoned Dremora (the Daedra thugs), and if killed, have the chance to drop their weaponry. (They will not drop their armour).

Comment: Daedric weapons don't appear in leveled lists until level 46; wouldn't this make them ineligible for random drop rolls from Dremora?

Comment: @Josh fair point. I'm not too learned in the restrictions of the random loot, but I know there is *some* restrictions.

Comment: Isn't leveled list restricted to the container and not to the player? I don't remember much, but I'd think that's how minimum-level dungeons can work

Comment: No clue; I suppose an easy test would be to make a new character, coc to Dagon's shrine and cheat the Dremora in there dead over and over, looting them to see if their Daedric weapons ever appear (you can do the real quest at level 15 or so, which nets four guaranteed Dremora fights, which is a pretty decent chance if your level doesn't influence their drops).

Answer (score -1):

When I first reached level 30 I found a daedric weapon and you can also use the bound sword spell because it is a daedric weapon with the same strength.

Answer (score -1):

I say go for conjuration you can get a Deadric bow, battle axe, and a sword.

Answer (score -1):

Once you get to lvl 47 go to the Thieves Guild where a girl named Tonilia often sells enchanted and unenchanted bows.

Answer (score -1):

I found Daedric armor in one of the giant camps near Markarth.

Comment: And I guess you are above level 45? Then you can find them just about anywhere.