# Where can I find a Daedric sword?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Where can I find a Daedric Sword?

Comment: Not sure if you're level 40, but this might help you: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/195046/skyrim-where-to-get-daedric-weapons-at-level-40

Comment: my main is level 189 and i can't find daedric lol.

Comment: Hi, if you're wondering why you're being downvoted. it's because the question has already been asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [skyrim wiki:](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Daedric_Sword)

> Unenchanted Daedric swords will begin to appear throughout Skyrim at level 46, though they may rarely appear as low as level 40. Enchanted swords can be found at level 47, albeit very rarely.

Just keep grinding and they'll show up.